# Change state of HTML page without refresh?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Currently, I have a mySQL database setup as follows:

```
fullname
address
cellphone
homephone
email
```

It is for users registering for my company. In the employee section of the site, there is a drop down menu, which is populated from the fullname row of the database. Is there a way using JavaScript/AJAX to display the entire column of data, based on the person currently selected in the drop down menu?

Comment: Is this an asp.net or php website? You would need a server-side backend to achieve this in an easy way.

Comment: What's the server side language ? If you plan to make a Javascript <-> mySQL application you are going to face big problems :)

Comment: Yes, there is a way, and you named it: ajax. Is there a question beyond that?

Comment: You should fetch the data using PHP and the included MySQL functions, and then fetch on the HTML page using an AJAX call to that PHP page.

Comment: @Jason, we're not here to write your program for you. Take a look at how PHP works, how AJAX works (perhaps with jQuery), give it a few goes and if you're still stuck then come back and ask us a specific question :)

Answer (score 1):

As pimvdb and myself stated, you will require a server-side language to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.

Look into jQuery 
http://jquery.com/ where you can create element.

Use ASP.NET to read the data from the SQL server, then make a jQuery AJAX call to your ASP.NET page, and finally display it.

Here is a snippet from my code, that should help you out.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOURPAGE.aspx/YOURMETHOD",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ 'upc':'" + value + "' }",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var yourelement = document.getElementById("someelement").options;
            //mess around with the element here
            }
        },
        error: function(){}
    });
```

Comment: i don't think he's using asp and he said mysql not sql

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with AJAX. Just have a page that prints the resultset formatted however you like. Then do a simple jQuery call like:

```
$("#personDiv").load("person.php?name="+$("#fullname").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

i highly recommend the use of [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com) and the use of [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)